# Which version of SAS is compatible with SAS Stored process version 2.0? Is it compatible from version 9?

Tags: sas, sas-dis, sas-stored-process

SAS Stored process 2.0 is compatible with SAS 9.3, but wanted to know if it is compatible with all versions starting from SAS 9 to SAS 9.4?

Comment: Note that (and as mentioned in Joe's documentation link) you do have the option to 'make compatible', ie convert from 2.0 to 1.0 if necessary.  Also, 9.3 will happily run 1.0 STPs.  Was there a specific use case you had for the 2.0 functionality?  It would be interesting to hear it..

Comment: @RaFocus Thank you

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/66819/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1vz7uqbo1vo10n11yip83icp6hc.htm), they are only compatible with SAS version 9.3 and forward.

> Version 2.0
>
> > Compatible with SAS 9.3 or later servers only.

Comment: But same SAS page says that SAS Stored Process 2.0 is introduced in SAS 9? So does that mean it is compatible with 9.1.3 as well?

Comment: No, it means it's compatible with SAS 9.3 and forward, not 9.1.3 or 9.2 (or the rarely-seen 9.0).  SAS sometimes uses the term "SAS 9" to mean "in some version of SAS 9" as if SAS integer releases were all one big product, versus the verity of each first decimal release being a full product.